# Convert text file to XML in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to convert a text file to an XML format. Even though its quite easy to implement this in Java, I was wondering if its possible to write a transformation that converts this:

```
Start Date Time     :21/04/2014
HTML Count          :2
JSP Count           :1
Word Count          :0
Type Count          :7
```

to this in XSLT 1.0:

```
<file>
<DateTime>21/04/2014</DateTime>
<item>
    <DocSubType>HTML Count</DocSubType>
    <Count>2</Count>
</item>
<item>
    <DocSubType>JSP Count</DocSubType>
    <Count>1</Count>
</item>
<item>
    <DocSubType>Word Count</DocSubType>
    <Count>0</Count>
</item>
<item>
    <DocSubType>Type Count</DocSubType>
    <Count>7</Count>
</file>
```

Comment: Short answer: no. The document to be transformed must be a valid XML document. But perhaps you could pass the contents of the text file to the processor as a parameter at run time?

Comment: A better use of XSLT in this situation would be to write a simple Java parser for your text document which generates DOM or SAX output, and feed that into XSLT for output formatting. In this case the output is so simple that it's probably easier to generate the final XML structure directly and use XSLT only as an XML serializer, but this is a good general approach for "importing" other data formats into XML.